# C# removing substring from end of string

Tags: c#, string, textbox

I have an array of strings:

```
string[] remove = { "a", "am", "p", "pm" };
```

And I have a textbox that a user enters text into. If they type any string in the `remove` array at the end of the text in the textbox, it should be removed. What is the easiest way to do this?

**EDIT** To clarify, I'm making a time parser. When you give the function a string, it does its best to parse it into this format: `08:14pm` I have a textbox to test it. When the focus leaves the textbox, I need to get the text without the am/pm/a/p suffix so I can parse the number only segment.

Comment: When should it be removed? You're obviously trying to solve a time dilemma. Maybe there is a better way to solve your problem entirely

Comment: When the textbox loses focus, the `OnLeave` event.

Comment: why Do you want to Doing this? Use Generic List

Comment: @TheAdam - don't you mean blur?

Comment: @Jack Erm... oh, yeah. Whenever the textbox loses focus.

Comment: But then you can't just strip away the am/pm designator, can you? Since 08:14pm != 08:14 but 20:14?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
string[] remove = { "a", "am", "p", "pm" };
string inputText = "blalahpm";

foreach (string item in remove)
    if (inputText.EndsWith(item))
    {
        inputText = inputText.Substring(0, inputText.LastIndexOf(item));
        break; //only allow one match at most
    }
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks! (Its making me wait 5 minutes to mark this as answer for some reason...)

Comment: A correct answer to the original question. Still, I would argue that if the user has written 08:14pm, she means 20:14. And as soon as you strip away the AM/PM designator, you cannot know whether the time should be parsed as 12 or 24 hour time.

Comment: if the user has written 08:14pm, then I will leave it like that. If they enter `814pm` then the program will need to strip the am/pm part off to process just the number part. Its added back in before its put back into the textbox.

Comment: The `LastIndexOf` call could be replaces with simple math because we check anyway that the `item` is at the end of string:  `inputText = inputText.Substring(0, inputText.Length - input.Length)`. 

But for me the best way is to use indices and ranges from c# 8:  `inputText = inputText[..^item.Length]`

Answer (score 39):

```
foreach (string suffix in remove)
{
    if (yourString.EndsWith(suffix))
    {
        yourString = yourString.Remove(yourString.Length - suffix.Length);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more efficient than the accepted answer because it does not have to search for the substring twice.

Answer (score 11):

I think that BrokenGlass's solution is a good one, but personally I would prefer to create three separate methods allowing the user to trim only the start, end or both.

If these bothers were going to be used a lot, I would create them in a helper class and/or as extension methods; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

```c#
public string TrimStart(string inputText, string value, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    { 
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText) && inputText.StartsWith(value, comparisonType))
        {
            inputText = inputText.Substring(value.Length - 1);
        }
    }

    return inputText;
}

public string TrimEnd(string inputText, string value, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText) && inputText.EndsWith(value, comparisonType))
        {
            inputText = inputText.Substring(0, (inputText.Length - value.Length));
        }
    }

    return inputText;
}

public string Trim(string inputText, string value, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    return TrimStart(TrimEnd(inputText, value, comparisonType), value, comparisonType);
}
```

With these methods we can modify the code for looping through the array containing the strings to be trimmed.

```c#
var content = "08:00 AM";
var removeList = new [] { "a", "am", "p", "pm" };

for (var i = 0; i < removeList.length; i++)
{
    content = TrimEnd(content, removeList[i]);
}
```

NOTE: This code could be optimized further, but will work as it is with a good speed.

Comment: I'd suggest making them extensions (use `this string inputText` as first argument), and defaulting to not be case insensitive, as C# defaults to case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your edit, consider using the built-in [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) or [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) methods followed by a String.Format. Here's a link to a [good resource on formatting strings](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
char[] remove = { 'a', 'p', 'm' };
string s = "8:14pm";

s = s.TrimEnd(remove);
```

Comment: -1: This will Change "8:14pamm" into "8:14", which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @DanielRose: I think this is exactly what the OP is asking. "If they type any string in the remove array at the end of the text in the textbox, it should be removed." And: "I need to get the text without the am/pm/a/p suffix". The OP is specifically asking how to get just "8:14"

Comment: The OP asked to remove the am/pm (or shortened to a/p) from the end. If the user entered (better example) "8:14mmmm" then your solution returns "8:14". But I would argue that the string is invalid, since "mmm" is not a valid time designation.

Comment: Wow. Over 7 years later and a downvote for an answer that still solves the question. Harsh.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good place for regex.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public bool IsValidTime(string thetime)
{
  Regex checktime = new Regex(@"^(20|21|22|23|[01]\d|\d)(([:][0-5]\d){1,2})$");

  return checktime.IsMatch(thetime);
}
```

Assuming you want time in the format xx:xx

Answer (score 1):

```
var output = (from x in remove
      where input.EndsWith(x)
     select input.Substring(0, input.Length - x.Length)).FirstOrDefault() ?? input;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `DateTime` as your primary type then.

Use `DateTime.TryParse` to read the time the user enters. And use `DateTime.ToString` to reformat the time using whatever format you need.

Comment: And if the exact format is known (such as hh:mmtt), DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParseExact can be handy.